# powershell Receive-Job find if State is Failed

Tags: powershell

I have a couple of Start-Job in a powershell script, I'd like to know if there is a better way to know if one of them Failed, this is what I got so far, thanks.

```
#Wait for the background jobs
$Jobs | Wait-Job
#Get the data from them
$Data = $Jobs | Receive-Job

Write-Host "Printing Data"


foreach($job in $Jobs)
{
    if($job.State -eq "Failed")
    {
        exit -1
    }
}

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
exit (0, -1)[$Jobs.State -contains 'Failed']
```

- Using [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375), `$Jobs.Failed` returns the `.State` property values of all jobs in array `$Jobs` as an array.
- `-contains 'Failed'` tests the array of values for containing string `Failed`.
- `[...]` uses the resulting Boolean as an index into array `0, -1`; if the Boolean is `$false`, it is coerced to index `0`, if it is `$true` it is coerced to `1`, thereby choosing the appropriate exit code.